# How to use gofmt to replace single quote with double quote

Tags: go

I use go 1.6 and I love using single quotes. After I finish editing my file, in my terminal I'd like to use gofmt for replacing them, but nothing works.

```
    gofmt -r "'->\"" book.go
    parsing pattern ' at 1:1: rune literal not terminated
```

I use zsh.

Comment: gofmt isn't meant for this and it can't do this. Try some tool made for this purpose, such as sed. Or even better: just write correct Go code in the first place. What's so special about single quotes?

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> $ go doc cmd/gofmt
> ```
>
> Gofmt formats Go programs.
>
> The flags are:
>
> ```
> -r rule
>   Apply the rewrite rule to the source before reformatting.
> ```
>
> The rewrite rule specified with the -r flag must be a string of the
>   form:
>
> ```
> pattern -> replacement
> ```
>
> Both pattern and replacement must be valid Go expressions. In the
>   pattern, single-character lowercase identifiers serve as wildcards
>   matching arbitrary sub-expressions; those expressions will be
>   substituted for the same identifiers in the replacement.

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Expressions)
>
> An expression specifies the computation of a value by applying
>   operators and functions to operands.

---

Both pattern and replacement must be valid Go expressions.